# Changing the source of struts select tag dynamically using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

In my code I have a Struts2 select tag(`<s:select>`). It reads something like this :

```
<s:select id="s" list="list" listKey="id" listValue="displayValue">
```

On some selection made by the user, I want to change the value of `list` attibute to point to some other list.(possibly using javascript/jquery)

Comment: If you want to use JS/jQuery then it is a front end concern, so instead paste the html that is rendered and show what you have tried with jQuery.

Comment: Why do you need something like that? I am just curious.

Comment: Note that since Struts uses the list attribute while preparing the page (server-side) you can't really "redirect" the list after the page renders (client-side). On the client side you can just manipulate the resulting html. Your options are essentially what Andrea describes below assuming you don't want to send a new (non-AJAX) request to the server and relod the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

[What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) *

You have at least two ways to do this:

1) Perform an AJAX operation to get the new data (in JSON for example, like a List of 'id' and 'description'); 
then alter the HTML with Javascript, removing the old `Options` from the `Select`, 
building and adding the new `Options` to the `Select`, 
and eventually changing some `Select` attributes;

2) Perform an AJAX operation to get a completely new `Select`, elaborated server side, returned as a HTML snippet (a JSP with only one `<s:select>` inside); 
then replace it to the original one on the page, for example using its container (like a `div`) as target of the AJAX operation.

---

* @AshishGupta suggested me to remove the "What have you tried ?" part to *keep the tone positive*. Please read the article, it is a *must* to understand why this should be always the first (positive and legit) question to askers who doesn't post code (for their own good in first place).

Hope that helps, as the rest of my answer.